# How can I put an IEditorPart in a modal dialog?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, modal-dialog

(I'm something of an Eclipse newbie, so apologise for any dumbness on my part...)

I have a number of editors (derived from `IEditorPart`) in my RCP app, and a requirement has arisen that one particular editor needs to be also available in a modal dialog box (along with some extra controls) opened by one of the other editor classes. The editor to be embedded consists of the main viewer control, toolbar, and a couple of dozen helper classes (label providers, comparators, etc).

The options before me appear to be:

1. Find a way to put an editor area, `IWorkbenchWindow`-style, into a (JFace or SWT) `Dialog`.

   - Not had much luck searching for how to do this
2. Create a new `WorkBenchWindow` with a Perspective that just the editor area visible, and no views. Make this modal.

   - On trying this, the new window seemed to inherit things (menus etc) from its parent window.
3. Refactor the editor in question so all of it now resides on a single control, then embed this control in both the editor and the dialog.

   - Potentially time-consuming, given the number of places the helper classes refer back to the main editor object.

If it turns out that this is a truly perverse and anti-idiomatic thing to want to do, in Eclipse terms, can you suggest a wiser course of action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EditorParts are meant to be inside workbenchwindows. There is a **lot** of code that depends on this behaviour. So I would suggest not to do (1). If the result is acceptable (a workbench window, which is modal), the easier way is to hang on to (2).

Comment: @prakash-g-r In which case, how should I:

    * ensure the window is modal? The only method I've seen for this is `Window.setBlockOnOpen()`, and that appaers to be a different framework. (And if it's created via `Iworkbench.openWorkbenchWindow()`, then on returning, it's already open modelessly.)

    * prevent the main window menu from being copied into the new window? (The action bar comes from the `ApplicationActionBarAdvisor` generated from the RCPMail template, rather than from defining extensions in `plugin.xml`.)

Comment: In your WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.preWindowOpen() method, if the workbenchwindow about to be opened is for the "editor window", then call configurer.setShellStyle()